# adding reference of separated project to more than 50 projects - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, resharper, multiple-projects

We had to separate a class library from core library project. And now, we should add the reference of the new project to the other 50 or something projects in a solution, which is ASP.NET MVC solution if it matters. Is there any way to automate this addition of reference? I have resharper but I can't find such a functionality with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VSCommands 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) enables you to copy and paste references (as well as several other very useful features).  Not quite automated, but much less painful than having to open each project's references and navigating to add ref.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to do some sort of search and replace in csproj files using NotePad++ or some other text editor.

You can also take a look at the Powershell console (I think its part of Nuget) and modify your proj files with powershell commands. Take a look here (deals with manipulating references): [how to find reference path via *.csproject file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313719/how-to-find-reference-path-via-csproject-file)

Comment: I thought about that too but I am afraid it might take longer than just manually adding the reference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: :) long for now, next time you'll have another tool in your belt!